# In which cases does my employer get informed?

Tags: online-learning, credentials

I was thinking of attending a Harvard Online Certificate, but I saw these:
https://online.hbs.edu/legal/ that it says about in which cases my employer gets informed.

So, what I want to ask is this:

1. If I use my university e-mail (I go to a different University) to register to the program, does my employer learn that I attend also Harvard Online Certificate?
2. If I give my university e-mail to Harvard Online, do they ask my University who I am?

I have a valid university e-mail. The problem is that I don't want my employer in the University I attend, to know that I attend also Harvard Online certificates program. There is nothing illegal, but there is no need for my employer to know that.

From https://online.hbs.edu/legal/:

> SOURCES OF INFORMATION
> We may receive information directly from you or from third parties such as marketing partners, social media companies, or your employer or educational institution if you are enrolled in our Services through or in connection with an organizational agreement.

> We may, for example, share information under the following circumstances:
>
> ....
>
> To report to your employer on your progress and participation in a Service if your participation in the Service is sponsored by your employer, and if you have so consented or we are otherwise permitted to do so.

Comment: "I cannot copy the text due to copyright law" - that's not how copyright law works. Please quote the relevant text here. Questions on this site must be self-contained and not require visiting an outside page to comprehend, especially because that page may someday soon disappear and make the question entirely useless to others.

Comment: Are you "enrolled in our Services through or in connection with an organizational agreement"? Is your "participation in the Service" "sponsored by your employer"?

Comment: I will pay the money for the certificate by myself.... no employer included...

Comment: I think you're responsible for reading and understanding the terms yourself, there's no special knowledge of Academia necessary here.

Comment: The way it is written, is a bit confusing to me...Sorry!

Comment: I think you're worried about "_or we are otherwise permitted to do so._". If so, I suggest you to ask Harvard directly. There is no way we can guarantee they will not inform your employer in some cases they are permitted to do so. It does sound lawyer's talk. You either let them give you black and white explanation about what exactly are the cases they are permitted to do so or you don't register the program. If you absolutely don't want your employer to know about it, I would not register if I were you.

Comment: However, I am wondering why you don't want your employer to know about it. Is there conflict of interest ? Or something you rather not tell us ? In general, there is no harm to participate in such a program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harvard Online is not likely to contact anyone about your online certificate.  You may request that they send proof of your studies to your employer.